# Complex numbers and Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, complex-numbers

Here I am stuck in solving Fourier transform and the funny part is that I am stuck in the basics, in the complex part. I hope someone can help me solve this part.

$$ 3 + 3 ( \cos \frac{4\pi}3 + j \sin \frac{4\pi}3 ) - 6 ( \cos\frac{4\pi}3 - j \sin \frac{4\pi}3 ) \over -16 \pi^2$$

If anybody is intrested in the question let me know.

Fourier transform:

another question is: how can I find the Fourier transform of 
$$f(t) = e^{3t} ( H(t+2) - H(t) )$$

I will highly appreciate the steps of the answers.

peace..

Comment: Would you mind saying what the function you're trying to Fourier transform is, please, and the process which led you to the algebra you're stuck on?

Comment: I am in the process of trying to understand fourier transform , new in it . so i found this question 

given a periodic function with period 3 :
 f(t) = 
0 if -1<= t < 0 
t if 0<= t < 1
2-t if 1<= t < 2

so 1 sketch the graph of f(t) on the interval [-5, 7]
calculate the fourier coefficient 
sketch the graph of g(t) 
calculate the complex frourier coeffiecients Fn of f(t)
calculate and simplify the real coefficients a2 and b2 ,

i am trying to find out a2 and b2 now which led me to seek for help

Comment: given a periodic function with period 3 : f(t) = (0 if -1<= t < 0) (t if 0<= t < 1) (2-t if 1<= t < 2)